# Non-compact Kähler manifolds which admit a positive line bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, line-bundles

A complex manifold which admits a positive line bundle is automatically Kähler. Furthermore, if the manifold is compact, then it is projective by the Kodaira Embedding Theorem. In particular, not every compact Kähler manifold can admit a positive line bundle. What about in the non-compact case? That is:

> Are there any restrictions as to which non-compact Kähler manifolds can admit a positive line bundle?

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question. There are positive line bundles on non-compact manifolds which are not ample, see for instance the paper of T. Ohsawa "A counter example of ampleness of positive line bundles",  Proc. Japan Acad. Ser. A Math. Sci. Volume 55, Number 5 (1979), 193-194. 

On the positive side, a theorem of S. Takayama asserts that a weakly 1-complete manifold, which carries a positive line bundle can be embedded (of course, not properly) into a projective space. However, the embedding is given by a twisting of the positive line bundle with the canonical line bundle. 



Answer (score 5):

Take a K3, or a general $n$-dimensional complex torus $M$, $n>1$, without any integer (1,1)-classes, and remove a point $x$. You will obtain a non-compact Kahler manifold without any non-trivial line bundles (because its second cohomology stays the same). For such a manifold it's not hard to show that no positive bundles exist. Indeed, if there is a positive line bundle, it must be trivial. 
Then you would have a positive form $\eta$ which is exact. By Sibony's lemma
(see e.g. [arXiv:0712.4036](http://arxiv.org/abs/0712.4036), Theorem 5.1), $\eta$ is locally integrable around $x$. Then, by 
[Skoda-El Mir theorem,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skoda%E2%80%93El_Mir_theorem) the trivial extension of $\eta$ to $M$ is a closed, positive and
hence exact current. This is impossible, because $M$ is compact and Kahler.